# Erro ao tentar carregar abas do excel no Spoon Pentaho

Tags: microsoft-excel, pentaho

Estou precisando de ajuda, comecei a estudar a ferramenta do pentaho para utilizar o PDI,
Estou fazendo vários testes para aprender a usar a ferramenta, porem quando tento carregar um arquivo EXCEL. Não consigo carregar as abas do aquivo.
Já tentei atualizar as libs do POI mas o erro persiste.

Segue abaixo o print do erro
Após clicar em ***GET SHEETSNAME(s)...***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E agora print que aparece depois que eu fecho a janela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Ao desinstalar e instalar novamente o problema se resolveu, acredito ter dado algum erro na instalação na primeira vez, já que só descompactei o mesmo arquivo do PDI.